# Graphql Query getting called infinitely using relayStylePagination

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I am using `@apollo/client: 3.3.15` and `relayStylePagination` from `@apollo/client/utilities` in my react-native app. There are two weird issues:

> 1. `discoverPosts` lazyquery is getting called infinitely
> 2. `postsWithPagination` lazyquery which is in different screen also getting called infinitely once a request starts for `discoverPosts`

Below are the code snippets:

**cache.ts**

```
import { InMemoryCache, makeVar, ReactiveVar } from '@apollo/client';
import { relayStylePagination } from '@apollo/client/utilities';

export const cache: InMemoryCache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        discoverPosts: relayStylePagination(),
        postsWithPagination: relayStylePagination(),
      },
 });
```

**ExplorePosts.tsx**

```
const ExplorePosts = (props: any) => {
  useEffect(() => {
      getPagedPosts({
        variables: {
          first: 30,
          after: 0,
        },
      });
    }, []);
  const [getPagedPosts, { data, loading: loadingData, refetch, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery<
  DiscoverPosts.discoverPosts,
  DiscoverPosts.discoverPostsVariables
  >(DISCOVER_POSTS, {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    onCompleted(dt) {
      if (dt.discoverPosts) {
        const result = dt.discoverPosts;
        const page = result.pageInfo;
        setDataState({
          totalCount: result.totalCount,
          after: page.lastCursor,
          hasNextPage: page.hasNextPage,
          posts: result.edges.map(m => m.node),
        });
      }
    },
  });

  return (<View></View>)
}
```

Stuck with this issue for infinite amount of time now. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Seeing the same issue in our codebase, ever managed to find a solution for this?

Comment: @dentemm I don't remember exactly but I think one of these two had worked:
1. downgrading the @apollo/client package OR 2. Check if all the nodes have unique IDs.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out!